# Verificar si el input tipo file está vacío o no

Tags: php

intenté verificar si el input type file está vacío o no, que si está vació no ejecúte nada ni envie nada a la base de datos.

Lo que intenté usar este código de php

```
    $sql = "INSERT into fileup(title,image,fecha) VALUES('$title','$pname','$fecha')";
    if ($_FILES['imput_file']['size'] == 0 && $_FILES['imput_file']['error'] == 0)
    {
    //que no suba nada si está vacío.
    }else
    {
    //aquí ya sube algo si hay algo en el imput
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 
    header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
    }
```

Pero mi problema es que sigue subiendo las cosas a la base de datos y mi idea es que no suba nada a la base de datos si el input está vacío o no.

Comment: Puede ser porque usas `&&` en vez de `||` y por lo tanto, si no se cumplen las dos condiciones salta al `else`...

Comment: Porqué no utilizar simplemente ````empty($_FILES)```` o ````isset($_FILES['imput_file'])```` para asegurarte que no venga vacío o exista específicamente la clave que deseas?.

Comment: Para validar este tipo de algoritmos en PHP, no estaría mal hacer debug y revisar el contenido de `$_FILES`, no?

Comment: ```if (isset($_FILES['file']) == 0 || isset($_FILES['file']) == 0)
    {
    
    }else
 {
  if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
 
    header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
 }``` intenté con este código pero sigue sin funcionar y sigue enviando a la base de datos ¿Alguno me puede ayudar? @SoyCésarMora

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($_FILES);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: `isset($a)` te dice si `$a` contiene alguna asignación o no, así que la comparación `== 0` no tiene sentido en este contexto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user264129 divide y vencerás!

Primero deberías solucionar los condicionales, tantos como validaciones quieras hacer por ejemplo. Y luego cuando eso te funcione, te centras en la base de datos.

Con un simple script de formulario puedes ver que hace tu servidor cuando recibe o no una imagen.

Ejemplo de formulario básico para probarlo:

```
<?php var_dump($_FILES); ?>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Upload a File:<br>
  <input type="file" name="imput_file" id="imput_file"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
```

Solo con esto podemos ver que cuando enviamos el input sin nada el servidor recibe lo siguiente:

```
array (size=1)
  'imput_file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
```

Y cuando enviamos una imagen, por ejemplo un .png, recibe lo siguiente:

```
array (size=1)
  'imput_file' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'logo3.png' (length=9)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phphrdngH' (length=14)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 44827
```

Con estos datos ya se pueden crear los condicionales necesarios para hacer una validación sencilla y escribir en la base de datos cuando los datos sean los requeridos.

```
<?php    
// comprueba el contenido de $_FILES en cada llamada
var_dump($_FILES);

// asignas máximos y mínimos admitidos de la imagen
$maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 1; # 1 MB
$minSize = 1024 * 2; # 2 KB

// esto es para que sea un poco mas corto el ejemplo
$isEmpty = empty($_FILES);
$size    = $_FILES['imput_file']['size'] ?? 0;
$error   = $_FILES['imput_file']['error'] ?? 4;

// si no es empty el array de $_FILES y
// si error es 0 (no contiene errores la imagen) y
// si la imagen pesa lo mismo o mas que el mínimo establecido y
// si la imagen pesa lo mismo o menos que el máximo establecido
if(!$isEmpty && $error === 0 && $size >= $minSize && $size <= $maxSize)
{
echo "<h1>Yeah!!</h1>";
// Aquí puedes hacer todas las operaciones de base de datos,
// redimensionado, copiar la imagen...
}
// si no es empty el array de $_FILES y
// si error es 4 (no se envía la imagen)
elseif(!$isEmpty && $error === 4)
{
echo "<h1>No existe la imagen</h1>";
}
// si no es empty el array de $_FILES y
// si la imagen pesa lo mismo o menos que el máximo establecido
elseif(!$isEmpty && $size < $minSize)
{
echo "<h1>La imagen es demasiado pequeña</h1>";
}
// si no es empty el array de $_FILES y
// si la imagen pesa lo mismo o mas que el mínimo establecido
elseif(!$isEmpty && $size > $maxSize)
{
echo "<h1>La imagen es demasiado grande</h1>";
}
// si no cumple nada de lo anterior, simplemente carga el formulario, por ejemplo.
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>PHP File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Upload a File:<br>
    <input type="file" name="imput_file" id="imput_file"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Una vez tengas solucionado el tema de las validaciones, te puedes centrar en la base de datos y otras operaciones que necesites para guardar tu imagen.

Comment: Hola, tu código me funcionó, pero estoy obteniendo esto en el cuerpo de la página, ¿Cómo puedo quitarlo? ```array(1) { ["file"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(40) "63fb446c-bc51-46d1-be78-a649121359a6.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(24) "C:\xampp\tmp\phpECC1.tmp" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(28150) } }
```

Comment: Esa es la salida de `var_dump($_FILES);` Elimina esa línea y desaparecerá. El código es solo un ejemplo, deberías estructurarlo según tus necesidades.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias si me sirvió :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba este código a ver qué tal. Lo pongo como respuesta porque en un comentario no se va a ver muy bien...

Con los dos signos`!` y `&&` se comprueba que ambas variables son diferentes de `0` y entonces se escriben los datos, en caso contrario no hace nada...

```
$sql = "INSERT into fileup(title,image,fecha) VALUES('$title','$pname','$fecha')";
if (!$_FILES['imput_file']['size'] == 0 && !$_FILES['imput_file']['error'] == 0){
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}
```

Comment: tengo un problema, ahora no sube nada a la base de datos añadiendo los archivos, ¿que devo hacer?

Comment: Olvidalo, ahora tengo otro error que sigue subiendo los archivos de igual manera, mi código ahora es este ````if (!$_FILES['file'] == 0 && !$_FILES['file'] == 0){
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
}```